I created my own Python wheel and did "pip install" but get an error trying to run
I created a Python wheel based on these steps from Databricks. It didn't work on a cluster so now trying to do in Linux conda virtualenv.
The setup.py looks like this:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import my_test_code

setup(
  name='testpackage',
  version=my_test_code.__version__,
  author=my_test_code.__author__,
  url='https://databricks.com',
  author_email='me@company.com',
  description='my test wheel',
  packages=find_packages(include=['my_test_code']),
  entry_points={
    'group_1': 'run=my_test_code.__main__:main'
  },
  install_requires=[
    'setuptools'
  ]
)

I have a my_test_code directory which includes init.py and main.py. The main.py contains this:
import sys

def main():
  # This method will print the provided arguments
  print('Hello from my func')
  print('Got arguments:')
  print(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

I ran
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

That created
dist/testpackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

Then this, which succeeded.
pip install testpackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

When I do "pip list", it shows "testpackage     0.0.1".
So I put this in a script:
import my_test_code
main('oh great')

But I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wheel_conda.py", line 2, in <module>
    main('oh great')
NameError: name 'main' is not defined

How can I import and run "main"?
